# Jmeter - install plugin WebSocket Sampler

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests

I installed JMeter 5.0 without plugin on MacOS X system.
I would like to doing test in JMeter basic on WebSocket connections.
I installed JMeter 5.0 but without Manager Plugin, and i can't reinstalled it.
I also can't added install Manager Plugin.
I download file plugin-manager.jar and copy this file to the lib/ext directory in jmeter.but after restart jmeter still don't have Manager Plugin.
i dont know, how I can install plugin WebSocket Sampler, if enough download JMeterWebSocketSamplers-1.2.1.jar and move up to lib/ext directory and next do restart JMeter, or anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed JMeter using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) like `brew install jmeter` - you should drop the plugins manager .jar file to a specific place

1. Identify where JMeter itself is installed

   ```
   #which jmeter
   /usr/local/bin/jmeter
   ```
2. Check where this script points to:

   ```
   #ls -la /usr/local/bin/jmeter
   lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  31 Nov  1  2017 jmeter -> ../Cellar/jmeter/x.x/bin/jmeter
   ```

   where `x.x` might be different depending on JMeter version, ideally it should be the latest JMeter version which is [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) as of now. If the version is lower - run `brew upgrade jmeter` command
3. In above setup I need to put JMeter Plugins Manager jar to

   ```
   /usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.0/libexec/lib/ext/
   ```

---

If you installed JMeter by manually fetching it from [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page, extracted it somewhere and installed the plugins manager in `lib/ext` folder - you should be good to go, just make sure you run `./jmeter.sh` file, not `jmeter`